# Recompute arrangedContent

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to reload a model and recompute arrangedContent. The model appears to be reloading but arrangedContent is not being recomputed. Sorting data is fine, it's adding and removing data that's causing the issue.

```
reloadModelData: function () {
  this.get('target.router').refresh();
}
```

My template looks like:

```
{{#each project in arrangedContent}}
<tr>
  <td>{{project.name}}</td>
  ...
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Edit:

routes/projects/index.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.findAll('project');
  }

});
```

controllers/projects/index.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.SortableMixin, { 
  queryParams: ['sortProperties', 'sortAscending'],
  sortProperties: ['name'],

  actions: {
    ...

    reloadModelData: function () {
      this.get('target.router').refresh();
    }
  }
});
```

A button is what is triggering `reloadModelData`

```
<button {{action 'reloadModelData'}}>Reload</button>
```

Comment: Can you add code of your router, current route and controller? Whas is triggering `reloadModelData`? Where is it defined?

Comment: I've added the route, controller and button that is triggering `reloadModelData` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `model` hook is not being executed in your action. Why? Becouse you are executing `#refresh()` on `targer.router`, which is not a current route, but the `Router`.

#### So, how can you refresh the model?

There is a convention called data-down-action-up. It supports sending actions up, to the objects that are, let's say, parents for the data to change. Possible solution would be to let your `reloadModelData` bubble up to the route and handle this action in the `route`. Then, in that action you could fetch the data again and set them on the controller:

```
# controller code    
reloadModelData: function() {
  return true;
}
```

And in route:

```
# route code
reloadModelData: function() {
  this.store.find('project').then((function(_this) {
    return function(projects) {
      _this.get('controller').set('model', projects);
    };
  })(this));
}
```

If the result from the `find` will be different than it was, the `model` related computed properties will for sure recompute.

[Here is a working demo in JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/turona/10/edit?js,output) that compares your and mine solution.

Comment: I've added `toggleProperty('sortAscending')` to the `reloadDataModel` action on the controller (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sepejujifo/1/edit?html,js,output).


As you can see it works just like your example. Sorting doesn't appear to be a problem. It's adding and removing data then reloading the template that is proving tricky. 


I've checked the store in Ember Inspector and that keeps up to date with what's going on in the app. It appears it's just the template that is displaying stale data.

Comment: I've simplified the question to clarify exactly what the issue is.